# How do I access the Throwable in a Quarkus ContainerResponseContext?

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-reactive

I have a service using Quarkus 2.16.4.Final and resteasy-reactive. Inside of a `ContainerResponseFilter`, I want to access the Exception that was thrown by my service code. In Jersey 1.x, there used to be a `ContainerResponse.getMappedThrowable()` which provided this.

From digging in the `ContainerResponseContextImpl`, the `ResteasyReactiveRequestContext` does have what I need in its `throwable` field, accessible from `getThrowable()`. However, the `ContainerResponseContextImpl` doesn't expose the `ResteasyReactiveRequestContext`, so I don't know how to get a reference to the throwable.

Is there another way to do this, or is this a feature request?

I am expecting Quarkus to provide a way to find the Throwable thrown by my resources.

Comment: For now, I'm using reflection to poke into the ContainerResponseContextImpl.context.throwable, but surely there must be a better way 

Comment: I usually use ExceptionMappers to handle my Jax-RS/Quarkus exceptions:
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-nd/8.5.5?topic=applications-defining-exception-mappers-resource-exceptions-errors

Comment: I do have an ExceptionMapper, but I'm interested in some post-processing in the filter after an exception is thrown. For that, I need to be able to inspect the exception class from the ResponseContext object. In Jersey 1.x, this was possible through the `ContainerResponse.getMappedThrowable()` method, but I don't know how to do it in JAXRS 2 or how to access it in any Quarkus API.